# File Transfer of ISO files using ROBOCOPY and Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive, iso-image

I have these two products:

[Virtual iODD External Encrypted Enclosure Virtual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00S3G12E6)

[Samsung SSD 4TB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08QBL36GF)

I have a Sabrent SATA Driver Enclosure on the side connected to my main computer, with a Windows 10 OS. When I go to copy images from the IODD drive under the G:_ISO folder I notice that this error keeps coming up `Error 0x80070570`. I would like to know what is the cause of the error does it have to do with NTFS, FAT, or FAT32? Or does it have to do with something else? Also how could I copy images (.ISO) from the iODD to the Samsung SSD 4B with this particular error.

Smart Attributes Seabrant:

[image]

Comment: How large are the failing files? What format (NTFS or FAT) are the drives you are copying from and to? FAT32 cannot accept files larger than 4GB, so you will have to swap to ExFAT if you need >4GB support.

Comment: Error 0x80070570: The file or directory is corrupted or unreadable. Your disk might have bad spots. Please add the SMART attributes of the disk to your post.

Comment: @harrymc What are the SMART attributes? How do I found them?

Comment: Use an app like CrystalDiskInfo or Speccy.

Comment: @harrymc I added the picture but it won't show up in the post.

Comment: Put here the link to it and I'll add it to your post.

Comment: @harrymc https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz43m.png

Comment: @harrymc https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKKfR.png

Answer (score 2):

Source of this error may be damaged file system on disk. First backup all important files elsewhere and then run `chkdsk /f G:` on that drive (put proper letter before `:`) as an Administrator.

File system type does not really matter in that case. Errors may be on all of them that you mentioned.

After `chkdsk` will repair the file system you should be able to flawlessly copy files.

Comment: Okay I will try.

Answer (score 0):

The SMART attributes show a disk in a very good shape.

The only attributes that are negative in nature are :

- Newly Added Bad Flash Block : 1
  Your disk has had one bad spot since it came out of the factory.
  By itself, this is nothing. However, it seems that this bad spot is
  inside your ISO, so I suggest to re-download it.
- Temperature Exceed Count : 39
  Meaning that the disk has overheated 39 times since it came out of
  the factory. You should check the airways of your computer for dust
  and install some product that will alert you when the temperature
  is too high.
- Power Recovery Count : 1
  You lost power one time, and the disk's firmware had to recover
  its data on the next power-up. This might have caused some
  corruption on the disk. If your environment is prone to power cuts,
  get a UPS.

Run also `chkdsk X:` for disk X, and if it shows an error then run
`chkdsk /f X:`.

In general you might have lost a file (or even a folder), but the disk
is fine in general and you can recover from this error.